# Changing the ParameterDirection.Input to ParameterDirection.InputOutput

Tags: c#, sql

```
MemberChecker.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

added
**and Problem Solved!**

---- Here was the funny question!

Why does my SqlCommand accessing a Stored Procedure work only when I use

```
ParameterDirection.InputOutput
```

and not

```
ParameterDirection.Output
```

**An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@Customer' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection**

Here is some of my code:

```
        using (SqlConnection H20_Connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["H20"].ConnectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand MemberChecker = new SqlCommand("execute custom_x_Check", H20_Connection);
            MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@TN", SqlDbType.VarChar,50).Value = TNH20.Text.Trim();
            MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Customer_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = TNH20.Text.Trim();

            MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Customer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Out_TN", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Out_Customer_ID", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
            H20_Connection.Open();
            if (MemberChecker.ExecuteNonQuery() > 1)
            {
                Top.Visible = false;
                Bottom.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                Top.Visible = true;
                Bottom.Visible = false;
            }
        }
```

and my SQL

```
alter proc custom_Check

@TN varchar(50) ='',
@Customer_ID varchar(50)='',
@Customer varchar(100) out,
@Out_TN varchar(50) out,
@Out_Customer_ID varchar(50) out

as

select @Out_Customer_ID=Customer_ID,
@Out_TN = MainTN,@Customer = Customer
 from [vCustomerName]
where Customer_ID  = @Customer_ID or @TN = MainTN
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you are expecting something to be returned by your query, that is why `InputOutput` works and `Input` doesn't.

Comment: I just want that output variable.

Comment: Are you getting the error on this line:  `MemberChecker.Parameters["@Customer"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
MemberChecker.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

Answer (score 1):

`@Customer`, `@Out_TN`, and `@Out_Customer_ID` should all use `ParameterDirection.Output` since they are `out` parameters in your SQL.

something like this:

```
MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Customer").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Out_TN").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Out_Customer_ID").Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

Also be aware that your SQL will fail if more than one record meets your criteria:

```
where Customer_ID  = @Customer_ID or @TN = MainTN
```

As you astutely noticed, you are calling the stored procedure with an `execute` statement which is incorrect in this case.  Change the command to:

```
SqlCommand MemberChecker = new SqlCommand("custom_Check", H20_Connection);
MemberChecker.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Comment: It should work if you use `ParameterDirection.Output` (not `ParameterDirection.InputOutput`)

Comment: An SqlParameter with ParameterName '@Customer' is not contained by this SqlParameterCollection.

Comment: Are you still `Add`ing it on the line before?

Comment: `MemberChecker.Parameters.Add["@Customer"].Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;`

Comment: MemberChecker.Parameters["@Customer"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output....i tried;

Comment: You've messed something up.  Either you're trying to `Add` it twice or you're trying to set the direction before you `Add` it.  Please post (to your question) your exact code as you have it now.

Comment: You aren't adding @Customer in your code but are setting the direction of the parameter:  `MemberChecker.Parameters["@Customer"].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`.

Comment: Yep - you're not `Add`ing the parameters after your edit.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Pinch - Also, you may want to consider - for the sake of being consistent with naming conventions - change the `@Customer` parameter to `@Out_Customer`.  Just my $.02 :)

Comment: thanks guys for your efforts and time but the problem is still there.....i changed according to Stanley see above

Comment: @Pinch - `MemberChecker.Parameters.Add("@Customer", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 100).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;`

Comment: @Brain  -how's your sense of humor? MemberChecker.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;